# Sistema de colisão para jogo em html5!

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

Estou aprendendo um pouco sobre jogos em html5,css e js.

Fiz um joguinho muito básico, movimentação de player, inimigo e um **sistema de colisão**, veja:

```js
var canvas;//o elemento canvas sobre o qual desenharemos
var ctx;//o "contexto" da canvas que será utilizado (2D ou 3D)
var dx = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) horizontal do objeto
var dy = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) vertical do objeto
var x = 250;//posição horizontal do objeto (com valor inicial)
var y = 100;//posição vertical do objeto (com valor inicial)
var WIDTH = 500;//largura da área retangular
var HEIGHT = 200;//altura da área retangular
var playerImg = new Image();
var inimigoImg = new Image();
var xx = 505;// posicao x do inimigo
var yy = 100;// posicao y do inimigo

function myRandom(min, max, multiple) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) / multiple) * multiple + min;
}

function cn(){
 xx = xx - 1;
    inimigoImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/V2yQ9kO.png";
 ctx.drawImage(inimigoImg, xx, yy); 
 if (xx < 0){
  xx = 505
  yy = myRandom(5,200,5);
 }
 
}

function check(){ // checar colisao
 if (y == yy && x == xx){
  alert('morreu')
 }
}

function Desenhar() {
    playerImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/u13C8nt.png";
 ctx.drawImage(playerImg, x, y);
 cn();
 check();
}

function LimparTela() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function Iniciar() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(Atualizar, 10);
}

function KeyDown(evt){
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:  /*seta para cima */
            if (y - dy > 0){
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:  /*set para baixo*/
            if (y + dy < 175){
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:  /*set para esquerda*/
            if (x - dx > 0){
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:  /*seta para direita*/
            if (x + dx < 475){
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function Atualizar() {
    LimparTela();    
    Desenhar();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);
Iniciar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200">
        Se você visualizar esse texto, seu browser não suporta a tag canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém esse sistema de colisão está bem ruim, precisa está no exato X e Y para morte.
Isso acaba sendo horrível, pois o rato deveria ser morto também se isso ocorrer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer para corrigir?

Comment: Precisaria criar uma margem de segurança, algo assim? não sei :(

Comment: Sim, precisa determinar se x e y estão dentro de certos intervalos.

Comment: Tente usar uma API, seu jogo pode ficar muito mais completo em termos de fisica, por exemplo: https://github.com/jriecken/sat-js

Comment: É importante estudar sobre Bounding Box, essencial para entendimento de sistemas de detecção de colisão

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você está a fazer não está correto porque basicamente você está a verificar se um pixel colide com outro. Você deverá verificar a colisão utilizando areas/intervalos.

Aqui vão os tipos de colisões mais comuns:

> Box Collision / box collission

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Box Collision com mais de um rectângulo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Circle Collision

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Pixel Perfect  - ( ignore o facto de ser novamente um círculo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em um mundo perfeito você deveria utilizar a colisão pixel a pixel no seu jogo, porém se o fizer irá notar uma quebra considerávelmente nos FPS do seu jogo. Por esse mesmo motivo é comum o uso de rectângulos para representar a área de colisão de um objecto, é muito mais simples, rápido, e barato em termos de recursos para a máquina.

```js
var canvas;//o elemento canvas sobre o qual desenharemos
var ctx;//o "contexto" da canvas que será utilizado (2D ou 3D)
var dx = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) horizontal do objeto
var dy = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) vertical do objeto
var x = 250;//posição horizontal do objeto (com valor inicial)
var y = 100;//posição vertical do objeto (com valor inicial)
var WIDTH = 500;//largura da área retangular
var HEIGHT = 200;//altura da área retangular
var playerImg = new Image();
var inimigoImg = new Image();
var xx = 505;// posicao x do inimigo
var yy = 100;// posicao y do inimigo


var rectPlayer = {x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50}
var rectInimigo = {x: xx, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50}


function myRandom(min, max, multiple) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) / multiple) * multiple + min;
}

function cn(){
 xx = xx - 1;
    inimigoImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/V2yQ9kO.png";
 ctx.drawImage(inimigoImg, xx, yy); 
 if (xx < 0){
  xx = 505
  yy = myRandom(5,200,5);
 }
 
}

function check(){ // checar colisao
  // rectangulos para testar colisao
  // basicamente sao os mesmos que estao a ser desenhados
  var rect1 = {x: x, y: y, width: 25, height: 30}
 var rect2 = {x: xx, y: yy, width: 25, height: 30}

 if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {

   console.log("Colisão");
  }
}



function Desenhar() {
    playerImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/u13C8nt.png";
 ctx.drawImage(playerImg, x, y);
  
      ctx.rect(x,y,25,30);
      ctx.rect(xx,yy,25,30);
      ctx.stroke();

 cn();
 check();
}

function LimparTela() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function Iniciar() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(Atualizar, 10);
}

function KeyDown(evt){
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:  /*seta para cima */
            if (y - dy > 0){
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:  /*set para baixo*/
            if (y + dy < 175){
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:  /*set para esquerda*/
            if (x - dx > 0){
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:  /*seta para direita*/
            if (x + dx < 475){
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function Atualizar() {
    LimparTela();    
    Desenhar();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);
Iniciar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200">
        Se você visualizar esse texto, seu browser não suporta a tag canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Desenhei os rectângulos para você visualizar facilmente o que está a acontecer.

[Artigo MDN que menciona Box Colision e Circle Colision.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

Answer (score 2):

Setando um range baseado nas dimensões no rato (23x26) você consegue definir a colisão. Você pode subtrair o valor do rato que você movimenta (`y`) pelo do rato que se move (`yy`), definindo, assim, um *range*. Basta subtrair o valor `y` pelo valor `yy` definindo o o valor em que será considerado uma colisão. O mesmo com o `x` e `xx`:

```
if (y-yy <= 23 && y-yy >= -23 && x-xx <= 10 && x-xx >= -10){
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var canvas;//o elemento canvas sobre o qual desenharemos
var ctx;//o "contexto" da canvas que será utilizado (2D ou 3D)
var dx = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) horizontal do objeto
var dy = 5;//a tava de variação (velocidade) vertical do objeto
var x = 250;//posição horizontal do objeto (com valor inicial)
var y = 100;//posição vertical do objeto (com valor inicial)
var WIDTH = 500;//largura da área retangular
var HEIGHT = 200;//altura da área retangular
var playerImg = new Image();
var inimigoImg = new Image();
var xx = 505;// posicao x do inimigo
var yy = 100;// posicao y do inimigo

function myRandom(min, max, multiple) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) / multiple) * multiple + min;
}

function cn(){
 xx = xx - 1;
    inimigoImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/V2yQ9kO.png";
 ctx.drawImage(inimigoImg, xx, yy); 
 if (xx < 0){
  xx = 505
  yy = myRandom(5,200,5);
 }
 
}

function check(){ // checar colisao
 if (y-yy <= 23 && y-yy >= -23 && x-xx <= 10 && x-xx >= -10){
  alert('morreu')
 }
}

function Desenhar() {
    playerImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/u13C8nt.png";
 ctx.drawImage(playerImg, x, y);
 cn();
 check();
}

function LimparTela() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function Iniciar() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(Atualizar, 10);
}

function KeyDown(evt){
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:  /*seta para cima */
            if (y - dy > 0){
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:  /*set para baixo*/
            if (y + dy < 175){
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:  /*set para esquerda*/
            if (x - dx > 0){
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:  /*seta para direita*/
            if (x + dx < 475){
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function Atualizar() {
    LimparTela();    
    Desenhar();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown, true);
Iniciar();
```

```html
<div>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200">
      Se você visualizar esse texto, seu browser não suporta a tag canvas.
   </canvas>
</div>
```