# Verificação de Colisão de objetos - C++ com Allegro5

Tags: c++

Como faço colisão de objetos em movimento no C++

Eu quero saber se o objeto pode ou não andar, mas caso tem um objeto do mesmo, ele tem que mudar de direção.

API : Allegro5

Comment: Coloque aqui o seu código, que abordagens já experimentou? Como ajuda veja este [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296081/sistema-de-colisão-para-jogo-em-html5/296130#296130)

Comment: Por favor, coloque exemplos e explique um pouco melhor a situação. Assim a comunidade poderá ajuda-lo melhor